# Vega Lite : stacked bar from multi column

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I made this chart:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "title": "Table 1",
  "width": "container",
  "height": "container",
  "data": {
    "values": [
     {
        "DAT" : "2023-01-18",
        "CONNEXION" : 2307,
        "ECHEC_CONNEXION" : 1699,
        "CONNEXION_UNIQUE" : 531,
        "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE" : 198,
        "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE_PS" : 71,
        "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE_UNC" : 127,
        "SIGNALER" : 212,
        "DEBUT_DOSSIER" : 990,
        "SOUMISSION_DOSSIER" : 431,
        "DEVERSEMENT_SCOLARIX" : 42,
        "MISE_EN_PAIEMENT" : 21,
        "DOSSIER_FINALISE" : 6
    },
    {
        "DAT" : "2023-01-19",
        "CONNEXION" : 1239,
        "ECHEC_CONNEXION" : 808,
        "CONNEXION_UNIQUE" : 296,
        "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE" : 120,
        "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE_PS" : 50,
        "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE_UNC" : 70,
        "SIGNALER" : 104,
        "DEBUT_DOSSIER" : 351,
        "SOUMISSION_DOSSIER" : 233,
        "DEVERSEMENT_SCOLARIX" : 91,
        "MISE_EN_PAIEMENT" : 55,
        "DOSSIER_FINALISE" : 26
    },
    {
        "DAT" : "2023-01-20",
        "CONNEXION" : 840,
        "ECHEC_CONNEXION" : 650,
        "CONNEXION_UNIQUE" : 169,
        "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE" : 82,
        "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE_PS" : 20,
        "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE_UNC" : 62,
        "SIGNALER" : 58,
        "DEBUT_DOSSIER" : 170,
        "SOUMISSION_DOSSIER" : 132,
        "DEVERSEMENT_SCOLARIX" : 106,
        "MISE_EN_PAIEMENT" : 25,
        "DOSSIER_FINALISE" : 9
    } ]
  },
 "transform": [
    {
      "fold": [
        "SIGNALER",
        "CONNEXION_UNIQUE",
        "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE"
      ],
      "as": [
        "key",
        "value"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "DAT",
      "type": "nominal"
    
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative"

    },
    "color": {
      "type": "nominal",
      "field": "key"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

The 2 fields "SIGNALER" and "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE" are part of "CONNEXION_UNIQUE"
so that the result would be something like (sorry for the mspaint quality):

[image]

So that instead of being all 'staked', those 2 field would be stacked and embedded inside the field CONNEXION_UNIQUE.

Comment: How about faking it? Prepend a `{"calculate": "datum.CONNEXION_UNIQUE - datum.SIGNALER - datum.ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE", "as": "CONNEXION_UNIQUE"},` in the `transform` [vega editor](https://shorturl.at/aT179)

Comment: @kikon I think that is the correct approach. You should add as an answer so it can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Here's what I think is a full solution of the problem, based on [`layers`](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/layer.html). The two stacked properties `datum.SIGNALER` and `datum.ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE` were grouped in one layer and the one that included them, `datum.ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE` in another layer, so the two layers could be assigned different visual properties.

v4 of the schema can be used except for the `"width":{"band":0.9}` (band:1 is the default value and I included it only for symmetry reasons) - it makes the inner bands slightly narrower to show inclusion.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "title": "Table 1",
    "width": "container",
    "height": "container",
    "data": {
        "values": [
            {
                "DAT": "2023-01-18",
                "CONNEXION": 2307,
                "ECHEC_CONNEXION": 1699,
                "CONNEXION_UNIQUE": 531,
                "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE": 198,
                "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE_PS": 71,
                "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE_UNC": 127,
                "SIGNALER": 212,
                "DEBUT_DOSSIER": 990,
                "SOUMISSION_DOSSIER": 431,
                "DEVERSEMENT_SCOLARIX": 42,
                "MISE_EN_PAIEMENT": 21,
                "DOSSIER_FINALISE": 6
            },
            {
                "DAT": "2023-01-19",
                "CONNEXION": 1239,
                "ECHEC_CONNEXION": 808,
                "CONNEXION_UNIQUE": 296,
                "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE": 120,
                "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE_PS": 50,
                "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE_UNC": 70,
                "SIGNALER": 104,
                "DEBUT_DOSSIER": 351,
                "SOUMISSION_DOSSIER": 233,
                "DEVERSEMENT_SCOLARIX": 91,
                "MISE_EN_PAIEMENT": 55,
                "DOSSIER_FINALISE": 26
            },
            {
                "DAT": "2023-01-20",
                "CONNEXION": 840,
                "ECHEC_CONNEXION": 650,
                "CONNEXION_UNIQUE": 169,
                "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE": 82,
                "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE_PS": 20,
                "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE_UNC": 62,
                "SIGNALER": 58,
                "DEBUT_DOSSIER": 170,
                "SOUMISSION_DOSSIER": 132,
                "DEVERSEMENT_SCOLARIX": 106,
                "MISE_EN_PAIEMENT": 25,
                "DOSSIER_FINALISE": 9
            }
        ]
    },
    "transform": [
        {
            "fold": ["SIGNALER", "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE"],
            "as": ["key", "value"]
        },
        {
            "fold": ["CONNEXION_UNIQUE"],
            "as": ["key2", "value2"]
        }
    ],
    "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "DAT", "type": "nominal"}
    },
    "layer": [
        {
            "mark": {"type": "bar", "width": {"band": 1}},
            "encoding": {
                "y":{"field": "value2", "type": "quantitative", "stack": null},
                "color": {
                    "field": "key2",
                    "type": "nominal",
                    "legend":{"title":"key"}
                    
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "mark": {"type": "bar", "width": {"band": 0.9}},
            "encoding": {
                "y":{"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true},
                "color": {
                    "field": "key",
                    "type": "nominal"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's a [vega editor link](https://shorturl.at/dyKLW).

---

Initially, I proposed in commentaries a "fake data" solution, that is much simpler but with obvious disadvantages. It changed the data through a [`calculate`](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/calculate.html) transform that subtracted the two other category values from `datum.CONNEXION_UNIQUE`.

Here's just the `transform` part, the rest is as in the OP question:

```json
{
    "transform": [
        {
            "calculate": "datum.CONNEXION_UNIQUE - datum.SIGNALER - datum.ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE",
            "as": "CONNEXION_UNIQUE"
        },
        {
            "fold": ["SIGNALER", "CONNEXION_UNIQUE", "ECHEC_CONNEXION_UNIQUE"],
            "as": ["key", "value"]
        }
    ]
}
```

and the [vega editor link](https://shorturl.at/aT179).